# Razor syntax in <style>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor

what is the correct syntax for using Razor syntax inside a style tag of a view? I tried two different ways:

```
<style scoped>
    .test1
    {
        background-color: @Model.bgColor;
    }
    .test2
    {
        background-color: @(Model.bgColor);
    }
</style>
```

Both versions will break syntax highlighting and code indentation of Visual Studio 2012 (Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3).

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I've just tried this in VS2010 and it looks fine. What's the actual issue look like?

Comment: your style syntax is 100% right. In VS2012 it doesn't show any highlighting.

Comment: Hm, so is it a bug in VS2012?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
@{
    var mystyle = string.Concat("<style scoped> .test1 { background-color: ", Model.bgColor, "; } .test2 { background-color: ", Model.bgColor, "; } </style>");
}

@MvcHtmlString.Create(mystyle)
```

**Edit**

@IngmarBobe sorry, but I tested with these two examples on the same version of VS2012 and working properly.

```
<style scoped>
    .test1
    {
        background-color: @Model.BgColor;
    }
    .test2
    {
        background-color: @(Model.BgColor);
    }
</style>
```

and

```
@{
<style scoped>
    .test1
    {
        background-color: @Model.BgColor;
    }
    .test2
    {
        background-color: @(Model.BgColor);
    }
</style>
}
```

What type of data is "BgColor"?. In my tests "BgColor" is defined in this manner and it works well:

```
public string BgColor { get { return "#611546"; } }
```

Comment: Good idea. But it breaks the looks of my markup and it's too hard to maintain (I have too many of those).

Comment: @IngmarBode And all these are same or equal?

Comment: No, unfortunately the relevant styles are totally different. No pattern.

Comment: Andres: I am sorry, but none of your suggestions work for me. Well, let me be precise: Of course, the class definitions work in a functional aspect, i.e. the rendered page is totally fine. It's the syntax highlighting that is broke. Btw: My BgColor is just defined as yours (string property).

Comment: I'm using MVC 4. Do you think this makes a difference for the syntax highlighting? Well, I guess, it might...

Comment: @IngmarBode I try in MVC4 and work fine, I don't know. My Razor version is "2.0.0.0"

Answer (score 2):

**Preserve Highlighting:** (wrap the values in parenthesis)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .test1
    {
        background-color: @(Model.bgColor); 
    }
</style>
```

**In Foreach:** (place the foreach outside the style tag)

```
@foreach(ColorScheme colorScheme in Model.ColorSchemes)
{
    <style type="text/css">
        .colorScheme_@(colorScheme.ID) { background-color:#@(colorScheme.BackgroundColor); color:#@(colorScheme.ForegroundColor); }
    </style>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `@` is significant in CSS code it is likely the editor has difficulty determining CSS or Razor context.

Use a partial view to prevent breaking syntax highlighting for your main view.

```
public class StyleModel
{
    public string BgColor { get; set; }
}
```

**main view**

```
@model MainViewModel

@Html.Partial("BgStylePartial", new StyleModel { BgColor = Model.BgColor })
```

**BgStylePartial**

```
@model StyleModel
<style>
    .test1 {
        background-color: @Model.BgColor;
    }
</style>
```

Highlighting is still broken but it is confined to the much smaller partial view.

Comment: Hi Jasen, yes, this is almost the same idea that I came up with in the end. Now I have two separate style blocks within my view. One contains plain and simple css definitions (and syntax highlighting works great here), the other one contains all the definitions with Razor syntax (here syntax highlighting does not work).

Answer (score 1):

Since Visual Studio hasn't implemented (or is never going to implement) any native support for this kind of much-needed-to-be-solved problem for Razor, here is something that surely works...

Instead of starting out coding your CSS directly inside views (or partial views), simply have a **.css** file created within Visual Studio, solely for the purpose of being where you first do all the CSS coding. Then, simply cut/copy and paste the CSS code, when done, into the views where they are needed, and of course enclosed within **<style>** and **</style>**. Then, you can use all your Razor variables and stuff.

You will not have IntelliSence support for the CSS code in the views, as you've noticed, when they are mixed with Razor, and will have issues with stuff like CSS' **@media** and the likes. But as soon as the CSS code is in a view, simply find and replace all **@media** with **@@media**, and the likes, escaping the **@**'s. You can even use Razor's **foreach** stuff to implement repetitive stuff. And when you need to edit your CSS code again, you repeat the aforedescribed process.

Personally, I [will] never use LESS or SASS unless a client explicitly requires it. Razor is far better than both of them. You can use Razor to integrally and seamlessly use data from database in your CSS code and do much more. I will keep using Razor until W3C implements something to solve this problem of CSS variables and the likes.

Comment: And of course, you will sometimes have to use Razor's text tags to enclose CSS code when using foreach and the likes.

Comment: You can optionally have each CSS code groupings coded into partial views that you then render into views where they are needed. This totally guarantees IntelliSence and other Visual Studio functionalities working in your non-CSS-dedicated views.

Answer (score 0):

Had trouble getting the @ symbol to recognize in the middle of a CSS declaration. Got it to work with `string.Format`.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @foreach(ColorScheme colorScheme in Model.ColorSchemes)
    {
        @string.Format(".colorScheme_{0} {{ background-color:#{1}; color:#{2}; }}\r\n", colorScheme.ID, colorScheme.BackgroundColor, colorScheme.ForegroundColor)
    }
</style>
```